# In the app, I keep getting error in UNRESOLVED REFERENCE: ANDROID

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
```

These 3 lines shows error.
It also shows unresolved reference volley, JsonObjectRequest, method

Comment: Did you implement volley library in gradle?

Comment: Yes, I did @Amy

Comment: Just try to clean project once. Still not working post your gradle code where you import the library.

Comment: I am doing a food ordering app, and I need help with it. Can u help me @Amy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try implementing the volley dependencies

`implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:X.X.X'`

if you did then try this :

cleaning the project and rebuild again if it doesn't work
try invalidate caches and restart from `file -> invalidate caches/restart`
if it doesn't work try using a proxy or vpn for building gradle.

Comment: I am doing a food ordering app, and I need help with it. Can u help me @Omid

Answer (score 0):

You should try importing the pertinent libraries.
At build.gradle you should put

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:X.X.X'
}
´´´
```

Comment: I am doing a food ordering app, and I need help with it. Can u help me @Ignacio